# Zurb Foundation-Apps Integration with Karma + Jasmine

Tags: zurb-foundation, karma-jasmine

I am a newbie on foundation and angular, but I have managed to setup a foundation-apps project using foundation-cli; however, I am unable to get test runner working. I am using Karma with Jasmine testing framework, but haven't been successful getting the angular module to load. Any help would be appreciated! The app works fine, but the loading of resources to test using karma isn't working.

The error I receive is:

```
ReferenceError. module is not defined...
```

I guess it can't load 'application' which is my angular app. Any help is appreciated.

### directory structure:

```
/root
  /bower_components
  /build
    /assets
    /components
    /templates
    index.html
  /client
    /assets
    /templates
    index.html
  /node_modules
    ... local packages ...
  /test
  bower.json
  gulpfile.js
  karma.conf.js
  package.json
  test-main.js
```

### app.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('application', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',

    //foundation
    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations'
    ])
        .config(config)
        .run(run)

    config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlProvider.otherwise('/');

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: false,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }

    function run() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }

})();
```

### karma.conf:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Mar 08 2015 18:16:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
       'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'build/assets/js/app.js',
        'client/assets/services/*.js',
        'test/unit/*.js'        
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

### My Demo Spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('Sample Test',function(){

   it('should know that 2+2=4',function(){
       var simpleMath = 2+2;
        expect(simpleMath).toBe(4)
   })

});

describe("EventService", function(){

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("application"));

    var service;

    beforeEach(inject(function(eventservice){
       service = eventservice;
    }));

    describe("Events", function(){
        it("should return an array of items", function(){
            expect(service.events()).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and resolved it by referencing the foundation.js and routes.js files in the build directory prior to the app.js. Also, angular.js should be loaded as a part of the foundation.js being loaded so you don't need to load angular.js directly.

That said, once it was able to use module, my module 'app' was not loaded. Have you solved it since this post?